# How to incorporate jquery datatables with PHP and external Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am new to programming and I don´t have much experience, recently i have been following this tutorial on how to create a server side search form with PHP and Javascript. The forms
works fine as is but I would like to displaying the using jquery datatables instead.

Can someone demostrate how I can incorporate the datatables into this code please.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pesquisar com PHP e Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>List Countries</h1>

    <span id="msg"></span>

    <!-- inicio do formulario -->
    <form id="form-pesquisar">
        <label>Pesquisar: </label>
        <input type="text" name="texto_pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar pelo termo?"><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" id="btn-pesquisar" value="pesquisar" name="Pesquisarpais"><br /><br />
    </form>
    <!-- inicio do formulario -->

    <span id="listar-paises"></span>

    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php

// Incluir a conexão com o banco de dados
include_once "./conexao.php";

// Receber os dados do javascript
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

// Acesso o IF quando o campo pesquisar usuario possuir valor
if(!empty($dados\['texto_pesquisar'\])){

    // Criar a variavle com o caracter "%" indicando que pode ter letras antes e depois do valor pesquisado
        $name = "%" . $dados['texto_pesquisar'] . "%";
    
    // Criar query pesquisar paises
    $query_paises = "SELECT Code, Name, Continent, Region, SurfaceArea, IndepYear, 
            Population, LifeExpectancy, GNP, GNPOld, LocalName, GovernmentForm, HeadOfState, Capital, Code2
            FROM country
            WHERE Name LIKE :nome";
    
    // Preparar a QUERY
    $result_paises = $conn->prepare($query_paises);
    
    // Substitui o link pelo valor que vem do formulario 
    $result_paises->bindParam(':nome', $name);
    
    // Execcutar a query
    $result_paises->execute();
    
    // Recebe os dados dos paises
    $listar_paises = "";
    
    if(($result_paises) and ($result_paises->rowCount() !=0)){
    
        while($row_pais = $result_paises->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    
            // Extrair o array para imprimir atraves da chave no array
            extract($row_pais);
    
            // Imprimir o valor de cada coluna retornada do banco de dados
            $listar_paises .= "Code: $Code<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Name: $Name<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Continent: $Continent<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Region: $Region<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "SurfaceArea: $SurfaceArea<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "IndepYear: $IndepYear<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Population: $Population<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "LifeExpectancy: $LifeExpectancy<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "GNP: $GNP<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "GNPOld: $GNPOld<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "LocalName: $LocalName<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "GovernmentForm: $GovernmentForm<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "HeadOfState: $HeadOfState<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Capital: $Capital<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "Code2: $Code2<br>";
            $listar_paises .= "<hr>";
        }
    
        // Criar o array de informações que sera retornado para o javascript
        $retorna = ['status' => true, 'dados' => $listar_paises];
    }else{
        // Criar o array de informações que será retornando para o javascript
        $retorna = ['status' => false, 'msg' => "<p style='color: #f00;'>Erro: Nenhum pais encontrado!</p>"];
    }

}else{
// Criar o array de informações que será retornando para o javascript
$retorna = \['status' =\> false, 'msg' =\> "\<p style='color: #f00;'\>Erro: Nenhum pais encontrado!\</p\>"\];
}

// Converter o array em objeto e retornar para o javascript
echo json_encode($retorna);
?>
```

```
// Reeceber o selector form-pesquisar
const formPesquisar = document.getElementById("form-pesquisar");

// Verificar se existe o form-pesquisar
if(formPesquisar){

    //Aguardar o submit, quando o usuario clicar no botão executa a função
    formPesquisar.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {

        // Bloquear para não recarregar a pagina
        e.preventDefault();

        // Substituir o texto do botão para pesquisando
        document.getElementById("btn-pesquisar").value = "pesquisando...";

        // Receber os dados do formulario
        const dadosForm = new FormData(formPesquisar);

        /*for(var dadosFormPesq of dadosForm.entries()){
            console.log(dadosFormPesq[0] + " - " + dadosFormPesq[1]);
        }*/

       // Fazer a requisição para o arquivo pesquisar.php
       const dados = await fetch("pesquisar.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: dadosForm
        });

        // Ler os dados retornado do arquivo pesquisar.php 
        const resposta = await dados.json();
        //console.log(resposta);

        // Acessa o IF quando não retornar nenhum pais do banco de dados
        if(!resposta['status']){

            // Enviar a mensagem de erro do javascript para o HTML
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = resposta['msg'];
        }else{

            // Subsituir a mensagem de erro
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
            // Enviar a lista dos paises do javascript para o HTML
            document.getElementById("listar-paises").innerHTML = resposta['dados'];
        }

        // Substituir o texto do botão para pesquisar
        document.getElementById("btn-pesquisar").value = "Pesquisar";
    });
}
```

Comment: What you are describing is called [server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side). Note that you don't have to use the SSP class mentioned in the official link, you can build your own array, and send it back to your front end as a JSON object.

Comment: I agree with @FiddlingAway - you don't _need_ to use PHP for this. Your datatables will be in HTML and JS, but the data you use to populate the table would be in PHP. This might be helpful to you - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/844403/jQuery-Datatables-For-Beginners. And for SSP - https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side